# Best practice for declaring JavaScript objects with similar properties

Tags: javascript, oop, design-patterns, structure, prototype

For a client side JS application, I require creating Quizzes and Surveys. The domain logic for these objects is incredibly similar so I would like them to both inherit from one UserInput object, while they each have very few additional methods each.

I'm concerned with the best practice method of doing this. I was thinking right off the top of my head I can just create a UserInput constructor that acts as a prototype, and then dynamically add methods to both Quizzes and Surveys.

For instance:

```
function UserInput() {}
UserObject.prototype.sharedMethod = function() {}

Quiz = new UserInput();
Quiz.sharedMethod()
Quiz.quizMethod = function() {}

Survey = new UserInput();
Survey.surveyMethod = function() {}

Survey.sharedMethod()
```

However I wonder if this is just not plain monkey-patching, and implementing a similar idea to abstract classes in JavaScript would be cleaner.

```
var Quiz = function() {
 UserInput.apply(this, arguments)
}
Quiz.prototype = UserInput();
Quiz.prototype.constructor = quiz;
Quiz.prototype.quizMethod = function() {}
```

The immediate difference I see is in the first example quiz/survey are objects while in the second quiz is a prototype. Every page has a singleton of these items, so having a method on every instance of quiz (which is only one) does not seem that bad to me.

Which is preferred and why? (Or am I missing any better methods of instantiating objects).

Comment: Your second way is the typical way to do it. Though it's conventional to have constructor functions start with a capital letter, so `Quiz`. And it can be helpful to do `Quiz.prototype = Object.create(UserInput.prototype)` so that you don't need to invoke the constructor.

Comment: Oh, you're saying there's only one object of each type? Then it just doesn't matter all that much. I probably wouldn't bother with constructors at all.

Comment: Classes are a bit of a can of worms at least until ES6. So many opinions. You may wish to abstract the ugliness away, I wrote this for example which is one of the few to handle multiple inheritance properly: https://github.com/DominicTobias/extnd/

Comment: @cookiemonster Generally yes, however I cannot predict the full use case of the application yet so I want to be flexible and write reusable code. I understand the use of the second method now.

Answer (score 0):

The one I use is [available on github](https://github.com/digital-synapse/ds.oop) and it works well for me with a simple familiar sytax. Allows OOP concepts in javascript including classes, inheritance, multi-inheritance, polymophism, interfaces (code contracts), and enumerators

Heres an example of simple class inheritance:

```
/* using ds.oop.min.js */

var a= ds.class({
    type: 'a',
    constructor: function (x) { this.x = x; },
    mul: function (s) {
        this.x *= s;
        return this;
    }
});
var b= ds.class({
    type: 'b',
    inherits: a,              
    constructor: function (x) { this.x = x; },
    sub: function (s) {
        this.x -= s;
        return this;
    }
});
var o = new b(5);
var output = o.mul(3).sub(5);    // output = 10
```